# Using Explicit Waits in Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to use explicit waits before clicking some web elements.

I believe that the WebDriverWait isn't waiting the full delay before throwing the exception. It keeps skips to the except: immediately.

```
        try:
            saveLink = "//*[@id='top-level-buttons']/ytd-button-renderer[2]/a"
            save_present = EC.presence_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,saveLink))
            WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(save_present)
            button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(saveLink)
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
        except:
            print("Timed out save link")
```

I'm also having issues with send_key(), where it doesn't finish sending before continuing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add this:

`from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException`

and change `except:` to `except: TimeOutException`

That way, you can catch the exception that occurs when the WebDriverWait has expired. If it's a different exception, then we will be able to tell.

Also, you may want to change `presence_to_be_clickable` to `element_to_be_clickable`, as I don't think your current option is valid.

It's also possible that you link locator is not valid, in which case posting the page HTML will help narrow down that issue.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I had like 6 try/except blocks and missed the TimeoutException on the last 2. `presence_to_be_clickable` was what was incorrect, but my except bit was hiding that info. :)

Answer (score 1):

By catching all exceptions besides just timeout errors, you won’t know if other exceptions are occurring. If you explicitly only catch the timeout error and/or log the caught exception you will see what is happening.